# using pandas read 0th row of csv and save it into list

Tags: python, pandas, list

this is my dataframe:-

```
A            B            C           D
1            23           34          23
3            23           21           4
4            5            6            7
```

> what i want to do is read 0th row and add it into a list like this `[A,B,C,D]`
>
> (here this column name can be anything)

I have used

`data = pd.read_csv(file_path, nrows=0)`

But i am not able to add/store it into list

How to do that?

Comment: `data.columns.tolist()`?

Comment: i tried it already ,i just forgot to mention there, it doesn't work @RafaelC

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this:

```
list(data)
```

but it is more explicit to write like t his:

```
list(data.columns.values)
```

Edit: As RafAelC said correctly it is better to use `tolist()` like t his:

```
data.columns.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Try to use `tolist()` method instead of using built-in `list`. `tolist` is optimized for specific pandas and numpy types, whereas `list` is generic for any iterable

Comment: @Javaman Please consider this as well, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers